# how can i do multitask in one view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have one view ,in that i want to show table view with  mapview .

my problem is how can i process in both thing same time. i want to show this things same time so speed problem not come.

for more info i added image which i want to show.

[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand your question correctly. You can add multiple views to a View, you need to add the Map view and the table view as subviews of the parent.

Comment: First of all this app will be refused because you cover the google logo.

Comment: yes your app will be reject  use multi thread concepts for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at multithreading my friend.

Have your methods that manage the tableView run in one thread, and the map methods in another.

For instance, in your viewDidLoad:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadMap) withObject:nil];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadTableData) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: what this "performselectorInBackground" do ?